# Getting segmentation fault when accessing memory allocated by malloc()

Tags: c, malloc

I have the following code snippet, which is giving me segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    unsigned int n1;
    unsigned int n2;
};

int main() {
    struct node *nd = (struct node *)malloc(24356 * sizeof(struct node));
    for(int i=0; i < 24356; i++) {
        nd[i * sizeof(struct node)].n1 = i;
        nd[i * sizeof(struct node)].n2 = i+1;
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

When I did some debugging, I could find that the for loop was executing for some 3000 times, and then the segmentation fault occurs on this line:

**nd[i * sizeof(struct node)].n1 = i;**

I couldn't understand what is wrong in this code.
Can't malloc() allocate the amount of memory (~190 KB) I am asking it to allocate ?
If so, why doesn't it return NULL ?

Comment: This is not how arrays work. There's no difference in accessing an `int` array allocated by malloc and any other int array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines are the problem:

```
nd[i * sizeof(struct node)].n1 = i;
nd[i * sizeof(struct node)].n2 = i+1;
```

Change them to:

```
nd[i].n1 = i;
nd[i].n2 = i+1;
```

Remember, indices are not byte offesets.  They're element indices.  The compiler will automatically scale them by the size of an element.

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't understand what is wrong in this code. Can't malloc() allocate the amount of memory (~190 KB) I am asking it to allocate ? If so, why doesn't it return NULL ?

There are several misunderstandings in your interpretation of the use of malloc that make your code incorrect:

- malloc is a generic library routine that needs as parameter the *amount of bytes to allocate* and you **correctly** ask for space for 24356 cells by the size of one cell (64 bytes) or 1,558,784 bytes. (Around 1,5Mb, and not the 190kb you say in the question)
- Then, you access the array elements by byte offset, **this time erroneusly**, as you have defined an array of structs, you cannot get the 24,356 (and later) array elements.

The expression you use inside the array index can range only from 0 to 24355, and no more.

Change

```
nd[i * sizeof(struct node)].n1 = i;
```

by

```
nd[i].n1 = i;
```

As arrays must be indexed by element position, and not by element address (respect to array origin)